# upload data from excel file to database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Entity class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "rates")
public class ExchangeRate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalCurrency localCurrency;

    @Column(name = "rate")
    private BigDecimal rate;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
}
```

Excel uploader

```
public static List<ExchangeRate> excelToExchangeRate(InputStream is) {
        try {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("FX Rates");
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();
            List<ExchangeRate> rates = new ArrayList<>();
            int rowNumber = 1;
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = rows.next();
                if (rowNumber == 1) {
                    rowNumber++;
                    continue;
                }
                Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = currentRow.iterator();
                ExchangeRate exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate();
                int cellIdx = 0;
                while (cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();
                    switch (cellIdx) {
                        case 0:
                            exchangeRate.setId((long) currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            exchangeRate.setDate(currentCell.getDateCellValue());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            exchangeRate.setRate(BigDecimal.valueOf(currentCell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            break;
                    }
                    cellIdx++;
                }
                rates.add(exchangeRate);
            }
            workbook.close();
            return rates;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail to parse Excel file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The question is the following. There are four columns in my database: id, date, rates and localcarrency (where the data is taken from another table).
And in the uploaded file, the data looks different (that is, the table structure is different)
In the uploaded file, there are columns: Date and then the name (which in my database are taken from another table) and below these names are the numbers themselves.
How can I take data in code?

This is the data that I need to take from the file:

[image]

And now I'm getting no
correct data

1961    "1900-01-01 00:00:00"   1.04
1962    "1900-01-01 00:00:00"   1.04
1963    "1900-01-01 00:00:00"   1.05

Should be like this

[image]

Comment: Provide sample input layout and clarify what your issue is. Are you unable to read the data correctly from the sheet?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer
All right. My data is not read correctly.
How can I attach a screenshot here?

Comment: Just copy paste into question edit

Comment: Date USD EUR CHF MXN
04.07.2022 1 1,0422 0,9612 20,277
01.07.2022 1 1,0414 0,9611 20,2629
30.06.2022 1 1,0484 0,9551 20,1183

Comment: @XtremeBaumer This is the data that I need to take from the file

Comment: Into question, not as comment

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have corrected my question

Comment: You have to "turn" how you iterate the data. `sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()` to get the number of columns. Then you need to iterate over all rows multiple times to get the correct rate. `for (int i = 1; i < lastCellNum; i++)` and the date is always `row.getCell(0)` (or whatever the col index for the date is)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I updated again)
Can you give an example?)

Comment: I really don't understand what that new info should tell me

Comment: @XtremeBaumer This is just an example.
Can you post some code so I can mark it as the answer to my question?